# Как сделать поддержку разных размеров экрана в Android

Tags: android, разметка, android-constraintlayout

У меня уже есть готовое приложение, которое на эмуляторе открывается таким каким я сделал его в макете. Но при установке приложения на физическое устройство элементы расположены со сдвигом вверх, и получается, что некоторые оказываются друг на дружке. Абсолютно все компоненты размещены в ConstraintLayout, который заполняет весь экран. На телефоне, у которого экран другого размера, друг на друга наползают нижние кнопки "очистить" "закрыть", хотя друг от друга у них есть отступы. Пожалуйста, помогите исправить!

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">    


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="308dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:background="#b8efb6"
        android:visibility="visible"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvKof">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            *тут элементы, с которыми всё в порядке*

        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKof"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="коэффициент = 0"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/PresTag" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
        android:onClick="Clear"
        android:text="Очистить"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/scrollView2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:onClick="Close"
        android:text="Закрыть"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/btnClear" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: как же тут можно помочь исправить, если ты не показал, что нужно исправлять?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видимо, проблема связана с тем, что высота `ScrollView` у вас захардкорена в `308dp`. Из-за этого на экранах с недостаточной плотностью остальным виджетам (под скроллом) негде разместиться и они наползают друг на друга. Решить это можно, указав высоту скролла в зависимости от высоты экрана, через проценты, например:

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent =".3"
    android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
    android:background="#b8efb6"
    android:visibility="visible"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvKof">

</ScrollView>
```

строки:

```
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_default="percent"
    app:layout_constraintHeight_percent =".3"
```

указывают виджету, что его высота должна быть 30% от высоты родительского виджета (указывается числом от 0 до 1, где 1 = 100%). Вы, естественно, можете подобрать свое значение высоты.

**UPDATE**
Еще более правильным решением будет назначить привязку скролла к кнопкам снизу, которые в свою очередь привязать к нижней части экрана, так размер скролла будет всегда идеально вписываться в экран:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:background="#b8efb6"
        android:visibility="visible"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnClear"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/tvKof">

        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKof"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="коэффициент = 0"
        android:textAlignment="textStart"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="italic"

        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClear"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Очистить"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/btnClose"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnClose"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="16dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
        android:text="Закрыть"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="14sp"

        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Я применил предложенные вами изменения, всё вышло хорошо. Но на телефоне с маленьким экраном, когда я набираю текст в edittxt который в скроле, то из-за вылезающей клавиатуры полностью сжимается скрол. Подскажите, что сделать.

Comment: вообще это больше недостаток маленького экрана, чем проблема программиста, потому что клавиатуре нужно где то разместиться, но попробуйте в манифесте для активити указать параметр `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" `, тогда элементы должны не сжиматься, а сдвигаться за экран, не меяя своего размера.

Comment: так же, если поведение в режиме `adjustPan` вам тоже не подходит,   вы можете указать атрибут `android:isScrollContainer = "false"` в xml-параметрах `ScrollView`, это должно запретить сжимать скролл при появлении клавиатуры.